# Select data from table where but without

Tags: sql

I have a table like this:

```
NAME, SURNAME, TIME_SESSION

John, White, Morning
John, White, Evening
Alexander, Black, Morning
Carl, Yellow, Morning
Carl, Yellow, Afternoon
James, Red, Morning
James, Red, Evening
```

I have to pick up all the elements from this table where time_session = 'Morning' but without to pick up the records which also have the time_session='Evening' or time_session = 'Afternoon'. The result must be in this example:

```
Alexander, Black, Morning.
```

Any advices are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or alternatively (a different approach than Guffa's reply), you can use a single query with an `IF EXISTS()`:

```
SELECT Name, Surname, Time_Session
FROM dbo.YourTable t1
WHERE t1.Time_Session = 'Morning'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.YourTable t2 
                WHERE t1.NAME = t2.Name AND t1.Surname = t2.Surname 
                  AND t2.Time_Session IN ('Afternoon', 'Evening'))
```

Answer (score 3):

Make left joins against the same table, and check that there was no match for those:

```
select NAME, SURNAME, TIME_SESSION
from TheTable t1
left join TheTable t2 on t2.NAME = t1.NAME and t2.TIME_SESSION = 'Evening'
left join TheTable t3 on t3.NAME = t1.NAME and t3.TIME_SESSION = 'Afternoon'
where t1.TIME_SESSION = 'Morning' and t2.NAME is null and t3.NAME is null
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for people who have one and not one or more others..

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable AS t
WHERE 
    TIME_SESSION = 'Morning'
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM myTable AS s
        WHERE 
            s.NAME = t.NAME
            AND s.SURNAME = t.SURNAME
            AND s.TIME_SESSION IN ('Afternoon')
        )
```

OR if you are looking people who have only one entry

```
SELECT
    NAME, SURNAME
FROM 
    myTable 
GROUP BY 
    NAME, SURNAME
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Which you can then join to:

```
SELECT 
    t.*
FROM
    myTable AS t
    INNER JOIN (
            SELECT
                NAME, SURNAME
            FROM 
                myTable 
            GROUP BY 
                NAME, SURNAME
            HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
    ) AS l ON l.NAME = t.NAME AND l.SURNAME=t.SURNAME
```